# Javascript selector: complete form or element by element

Tags: javascript, performance

Say I have a form with many fields and I need select some of them to work on.

The better choice is to select complete form touching DOM one time or is to select element by element touching DOM many times?

I know about the "cache selector" practice and the implications of touching DOM many times, but I have doubts when the form is too big what approach use.

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
</form>
```

```
<script>
    //select complete form
    const form = document.querySelector('form');
    form.fname = 'My Name';
    form.lname = 'My Lastname';

    //select element by element
    const fisrtname = document.querySelector('#fname');
    const lastname = document.querySelector('#lname');
</script>
```

Comment: Could you show examples of the two codes you're talking about? You can use jsperf.com to perform benchmark tests.

Comment: @Barmar check again, now with code example.

Comment: Unless you're doing this very frequently, the difference is negligible.

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). Do whatever you feel is most natural and readable, and optimize it if it becomes a performance bottleneck.